# python for loop, appending data from 12 columns to 1 column

Tags: python

I am trying to determine what this loop does and if it can be done in a clearer way.

My understanding:
For each iteration of the loop, it's taking one of the user ID fields(Col1 to Col 12) and writing that to the ID_final field. And then it tries to use that to join to "data" dataframe. Then appends everything to final_hr dataframe.

```
column_list = pd.DataFrame(['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4', 'Col5',
'Col6','Col7','Col8','Col9','Col10',
'Col11','Col12'])

final_hr = pd.DataFrame()
 
for column in range(len(column_list)):
            hr_new=hr.copy()
          #Drop rows containing NAN for column 'col4' for new merge
          hr_new.dropna(subset=[column_list.iloc[column,0]], inplace = True)
          #Creating a new column for merge
           hr_new['ID_final']=hr_new[column_list.iloc[column,0]]
           #case folding
           hr_new['ID_final']=hr_new['ID_final'].str.strip().str.upper()
           #Merge data
          merged_data = pd.merge(hr_new, data, how='left', left_on='ID_final', right_on ='OtherID')
           #Concatinating all data together
            final_hr = final_hr.append(merged_data)
 
HR_attestation = final_hr.drop_duplicates()
```

I have trouble understanding how this exactly works.

In this output, i am unsure how the user "BADAWI6" from Col4 becomes the ID_Final. Why isnt Col1 or Col7 becoming the ID_Final here?

[image]

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. If you use `print(hr_new)` after every line then you will see how it change DataFrame.

Comment: it doesn't get `ID fields` but column's name and every loop works with full column. I think it could use normal list with column's names. and `for column in column_list:` and later use `column` instead of `column_list.iloc[column,0]` - so code could be shorter and more readable.

Comment: What does this line do : `final_hr = final_hr.append(merged_data)`

Comment: if `final_hr` is `DataFrame` then it creates new `DataFrame` with data from `final_hr` and `merged_data`  - which you have to assign to some variable - but it doesn't change original `final_hr`. If you assign it again to `final_hr` then you can use it again in next loop.

Comment: @furas but how does the loop affect the `append`  of `merged_data` to `final_hr`?

Comment: you assign again to the same variable. If you don't assign to `final_hr` then it don't change `final_hr`. If you use `print(final_hr)` inside loop then you can see how `final_hr` is changing